# PhpStorm - Wrap curly braces {} in one line if the body of method is empty

Tags: php, phpstorm

With PHP 8 we can use promoted properties in class constructor. How can I tell PhpStorm to wrap curly braces `{}` together "if the body of the method was empty" ? like:

```php
public function __construct(private Collection $urls){}
```

But PhpStorm reformat this as :

```php
public function __construct(private Collection $urls)
{
}
```

Comment: this is just a tweak to add in the code formating section of the settings, but it's totally possible indeed (I just don't remember the exact spot)

Comment: there is a option called "simple methods in one line" but i want something that only apply on methods that have empty body

Comment: if you don't find anything useful in the settings, you could try to make your own plugin, it wmay not be the best solution, but you would have what you want at least

Comment: @Mwthreex If it's not possible to achieve with current functionality then consider filling a Feature Request ticket at the PhpStorm Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Ok i did https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57579

Comment: replied on YT: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57579#focus=Comments-27-4599856.0-0, will keep you posted there